# Can I release material related to a work and maintain my rights before publishing?

Tags: creative-commons

I don't know how many writers here are into the techy side of life, but I am wondering, if say. someone is writing the next star trek, is it safe to go ahead and release related material under a (restrictive of course) creative commons license?

For example, if you are writing some fantasy fiction series, is it safe to create character profiles (under a cc) (like say, as a pdf or something)?

PS. This is not the same idea as my [wiki question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/is-it-safe-to-create-a-wiki-for-a-book-or-something-featured-in-it-before-the-b).

Comment: Define "safe." From what? Are you asking about what rights you would maintain? I think you need to rephrase this a bit to clarify your question. (Although if you are writing Star Trek, then no, you're not safe from Paramount's lawyers. :) )

Comment: @Lauren lol! Good humour about star trek :D! I am talking about maintaining rights, I will try to rephrase the question a bit.

Comment: Is this material you own copyright for?

Comment: @wayOutwest as in created it? or as in went through some loop-de-loop process for?

Comment: You automatically own the copyright to anything you create; you don't have to loop any loops. My question (on this and your wiki question) is WHY do you want to release your ideas to the public before the book is done?

Comment: @Lauren I guess because some of the ideas existed long before I even thought to write anything, and I always had a habit of sharing (from childhood) about my imaginations/ideas. Plus I'm a Christian and bit of an open source enthusiast, so I it kinda rubs off... (all the share! share! share! -ness :P). Apart from just sharing, some of my reasoning is based on wanting to form a community around an idea first (before forming a community around a "book"). Thanks btw! (I'm almost out of space for this comment :D).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Howard Aiken said:

> Don't worry about people stealing an idea. If it's original, you will have to ram it down their throats.

As a beginner writer, your challenge is to get people to notice you and take your ideas seriously, rather than someone steal from you.

So feel free to share your ideas. Its not the ideas that are important, but how you implement those ideas. Rather than focussing on the wrong thing (people stealing your ideas), focus on how you can market yourself and your work.

Edit: And to answer your other question: As Lauren Ipsum said, you own the rights to anything you create. But you have to ask yourself: Why would anyone steal ideas from an unknown writer? Would anyone even notice you wiki, among the millions of other sites?

Comment: To answer if anyone would notice (as I am a web developer) - yes, they would ;). Trust me, even the most obscure sites get noticed within hours or days. With that said - you're pretty encouraging :D! Thanks!